# Way to speed up cp -a (using cp -a within a thumb drive is very slow)

Tags: command-line, live-usb, cpu-load, persistence, cp

When using a thumb drive with a persistent operating system, it happens that the persistent partition `casper-rw` gets corrupted, if one pulls out the thumb drive too early after shutting down the operating system.

Unfortunately with ubuntustudio-20.04.2 I experienced periods of up to one minute after clicking the shutdown button when the screen is black, but heavy write operations happen to the `casper-rw` partition. So it can happen very easily to wreck it by pulling the stick too early.

In order to recover from such a mishap, I create a backup partition for `casper-rw` and I use commands (after becoming super user) after properly setting the variables QUELLE and ZIEL:

`time cp -a "${QUELLE}/upper"      "${ZIEL}"`

`time cp -a "${QUELLE}/work"       "${ZIEL}"`

`time cp -a "${QUELLE}/lost+found" "${ZIEL}"`

When my script runs, I see

- very low CPU activity
- very little RAM usage
- `htop` shows me that the `cp -a` process is very much time in state D.

If I got it right (please correct me), this means that the computer has to wait very often because the USB stick's controller can't handle these many read and write operations effectively (although it is a USB3 device in a USB3 socket!).

**Is there a way to let** `cp -a` **use larger buffers in order to speed up things, ideally writing whole files sequentially?**

Comment: I would imagine the problem is indeed large buffers in the first place - a large number of operations get buffered, the buffer gets full, is flushed, and that causes `cp` to twiddle thumbs in `D` while the flushed operations are completed.

Comment: Myself, I would use rsync instead, therefore only replacing files that need replacing.

Comment: Muru, do you mean this problem (back from 2013):  https://lwn.net/Articles/572911/. As a remedy https://gist.github.com/2E0PGS/f63544f8abe69acc5caaa54f56efe52f recommend fiddeling with ```/proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes``` and ```/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes```. My findings were on an ext2 partition on an USB3-Stick mounted on an USB3 socket. This all with kernel 5.4.0-72-generic x86_64.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one can significantly speed up copying by first copying the directories `upper`, `work` and `lost+found` (if it exists) in partition `casper-rw` to some directory on a SSD. This step takes slightly more than 2 minutes. One can use `cp -a` for that purpose.

If you want the backup on the same stick in a separate partition, copying it from the SSD to the USB-Stick with `cp -a` took something like 31 minutes (for 4,1 GiB of data in some 66500 files, USB3 stick in an USB3 socket). The previous content of the partition had been wiped by `rm -rf "${ZIEL}/upper"; rm -rf "${ZIEL}/work"; rm -rf "${ZIEL}/lost+found` before any now content was copied to the backup partition).

Does anybody know whether it makes a difference if a partition was wiped this way before re-use or if it would speed up even more if one would format over it before the net content is placed there? In case of a wrecked `casper-rw` one has to format it before restoring its content from backup.

Of course one could further improve that by making a backup as `backup.tar.gz`. This reduces the amount of data to be written and especially the second step would profit from that.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `sync` to force immediate writing to the destination

When you `cp` a file and it appears at the destination file-system, it is not guaranteed that the file is actually on the storage medium yet.

The reason for that is, that the data is first fetched in between various internal buffers, which is faster and user-friendlier, until it actually is on the destination storage device. Writing the data to the destination device is actually performed in the background and does not consume many CPU cycles, that's why it might be difficult to see it in the activity monitors.

You can always try to force an immediate write from the buffers to the destination storage device by using `sync` after the copy, e.g. `cp ${QUELLE} ${ZIEL} && sync`

Also, consider using `rsync` to only copy files to the destination that have been changed or are new.

Comment: flush --help returned me nothing about flush. to which package does it belong?

Comment: would rsync -a be the right thing? But in my case, I have to wipe the whole target directory first, so files which have changed or which are newer would make no difference in my application.

Comment: I'm sorry, I erroneously put down a wrong command. I use an alias `flush` that does some other things as well, but the actual command I meant is called `sync`

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Before adding ```&&``` sync, copying the content from one partition of the stick to another one costs e.g. real 67m51,688s/user 0m1,623s/sys 0m19,335s. After adding ```&& sync``` to my script it costs real 59m34,347s/user 0m1,632s/sys 0m18,157s. This is still much more time than it takes to copy the full  thumb drive (at least 4 times as much data) to another one using ```dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdd  ibs=1M```. Of course, the comparison is somewhat unfair. But with reasonable buffering, the OS should do better. There is plenty of RAM unused during copying.

Comment: This is not surprising. Please see that `dd` operates on ‘raw’ block level in a linear way and does not have to concern with file system specifics which could bring random placement of blocks. Even if we are now talking in the domain of Flash memory, linear writing will always be faster than random writing + filesystem overhead.

Comment: Now I have tried it with commands like this: ```time rsync -a "${QUELLE}/upper"      "${ZIEL}" && sync```. Surprisingly the execution time was more than doubled (real 127m6,547s / user 62m52,151s / sys 15m39,477s) with respect to ```cp -a``` (see above). Further one error message ending with ```... 5.8.0-50-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/block/cryptoloop.ko": No space left on device (28)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(393) [receiver=3.1.2]``` - but more than 9.5GB of 11,6GB un the target partition are free!